# How to recover SQL Server ownership when NT account is not valid anymore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, sa

I have a local SQL Server Express 2005, for which I don't know the SA password. I always connected with my NT login and I used that when I created a DB I want to access now.

My company split and I am a member of a new domain now. There are no connections with the old domain anymore. My account resides in the new user domain and is a local administrator on the computer where SQL Server runs.

I can access the Server through the Management Studio, but not my user DB anymore. I am not recognized as a Server Admin anymore either. Obviously, local NT administrators are not automatically mapped to be SQL Admins.

Is there a way to do that at this stage? Can I somehow recover access to the SA level of access?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not having tried this myself, but running the database in single user mode should give you SQL Server Admin privileges if you are a Windows Administrator on that local machine.

```
SQLServr.Exe –m
```

Found a technet post that describes the full procedure:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2011/06/14/tips-amp-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you may find this solution elegant:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2682/recover-access-to-a-sql-server-instance/#comments
For me it did not work with SQL2016 but as the author states, it worked for him in older versions of MS SQL.
Quotes (from the above link):
Thanks to Mark Russinovich of Sysinternals fame, there is a very painless way to solve this problem without any downtime: PsExec. While it wasn't one of its primary design goals, PsExec allows you to run programs as the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, which - unlike "regular" Administrator accounts - has inherent access to SQL Server.
PsExec -s -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe"
Now, you can go in to Security > Logins and add your account as a sysadmin, add other admin accounts, update the sa password, and do anything else you need to do to make your instance manageable. As you can see, I was able to connect in this way to both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 instances from an instance of Management Studio 2012.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Quote the part you've copy-pasted from the URL with actual quote formatting (start the line with a `>`). See [the referencing guide](/help/referencing)